# pandas indexing using multiple isin clauses

Tags: python, pandas

If I want to do is-in testing on multiple columns at once, I can do:

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> df = DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 4, 7], 'C' : [10, 12, 18]})   
>>> mask = df[['A','B']].isin({'A': [1, 3], 'B': [4, 7, 12]}).all(axis=1)
>>> df = df[mask]
```

That works--is there a more succinct solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TBH, your current approach looks fine to me; I can't see a way with `isin` or `filter` to improve it, because I can't see how to get `isin` to use only the columns in the dictionary or `filter` to behave as an `all`.

I don't like hardcoding column names, though, so I'd probably write this as

```
>>> keep = {'A': [1, 3], 'B': [4, 7, 12]}
>>> df[df[list(keep)].isin(keep).all(axis=1)]
   A  B   C
2  3  7  18
```

or with `.loc` if I needed a handle.

Answer (score 21):

You could put both the `isin` conditions in `&`

```
df[df['A'].isin([1, 3]) & df['B'].isin([4, 7, 12])]
   A  B   C
2  3  7  18
```

You could also use `query` function like

```
c_a = [1, 3]
c_b = [4, 7, 12]
df.query('(B in @c_b) & (A in @c_a)')

   A  B   C
2  3  7  18
```

Comment: Note that `in` is case sensitive (Unlike `IN` in SQL)

Answer (score 6):

You could put both conditions in as a mask and use `&`:

```
In [12]:

df[(df['A'].isin([1,3])) & (df['B'].isin([4,7,12]))]
Out[12]:
   A  B   C
2  3  7  18
```

Here the conditions require parentheses `()` around them due to operator precedence

Slightly more readable is to use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query):

```
In [15]:

df.query('A in [1,3] and B in [4,7,12]')
Out[15]:
   A  B   C
2  3  7  18
```